# main.out.xml error

Tags: xml

I installed Eclipse and Android ADT.  When I create android project and try to run, I get following on main.out.xml file:
This document is empty.
Right click here to insert content

However, main.xml file has xml data for layout.

Please help what I need to do after right clicking.  Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393103/android-sdk-main-out-xml-parsing-error

Answer (score 1):

Delete main.out.xml ; and run as Android application.

I wrote a blog about solving this problem, check the following link for detail

[situee.blogspot.com : Unparsed aapt error, main.out.xml](http://situee.blogspot.com/2011/02/unparsed-aapt-error-mainoutxml.html)

Answer (score 1):

delete main.out.xml / string.out.xml, and Run -> Run as Android App. would solve this problem.

this problem is caused because eclipse automatically uses XSLT on xml when you press Run. Deleting main.out.xml is annoying, and you could modify launching operation in Windows->Preference->Run/Debug->Launching->Launching Operation->Always launch the previously launched application.
(my eclipse version is Indigo JavaEE)

hope this may help.

Acknowledgement:
http://www.cnblogs.com/chunhui588/archive/2010/06/26/Android-debug-main-out-xml-parsing-error.html (It's in chinese but the pictures might still be useful.)