# Android Emulator do not scale to 100% for Mac Book Pro with Retina Display

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, retina-display

Not much help on SO or Google about this. On a Macbook Pro Retina, my Emulator is 1/4 of the real size and clicks are not working properly. Please help to setup my emulator for retina display.

For clarification, the image of the emulator is scaled down to 1/4th of the available emulator window, but the clicks register across the entire window.  So to unlock the device, for example, you need to guess where the unlock button is in the part of the window that is blank and then click and drag from there.

Here's an image that illustrates this (hat tip Corey D):

[image: Tap/click region vs. display region]

Comment: But emulator @ 100% will cover almost 0.25 of the retina display. You may need 200% or bigger (never tried myself if > 100% is supported)

Comment: Whatever the skin type I use its always 1/4 of the emulator window.

Comment: A workaround to this emulator issue is to use a tool like setresx or switchresx to set a non retina resolution while starting emulator. then you can revert to your retina resolution, emulator will stay as it should be. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33383 for more details.

Comment: I solved it by using virtual box and this http://www.buildroid.org/blog/?page_id=121 (builddroid) not only is it faster it also works good on the retina.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Now that I can work with! Edited. Popularity may not equal quality, but it equals demand. It may not have been the most complete question, but in the interest of helping the community as quickly as possible, it should have been left open or advice to help improve it should have been given earlier.

Comment: @BenJakuben There's advice on improving questions on the page where people ask questions.  It was also linked in the blurb of text that explained the close reason.  We just don't have time to guide everyone individually.  Thanks a lot for taking the time to improve this question though.  It's much appreciated.

Comment: Since Retina display are getting popular, lot of Dev will find this issue and they will run to SO. Great effort by James to consolidate and keep it as simple as it could be. Hurray n happy coding on new retina devices.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Thanks Bill, sounds like I missed it in the close reason. Either way, I'm glad to see it reopened and improved!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known issue. We are working on a fix.

EDIT:

[Link to issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33383)

Comment: First... Thank for all of your hard work. Secondly, I assume there is no workaround other than using device or virtualbox solution in the meantime.

Comment: See my response with link, if you need a fix ASAP it has been fixed in ADT-21 developer preview.

Answer (score 11):

This has been fixed in the [ADT21 preview](http://tools.android.com/download/adt-21-preview)

You can enable the Preview Tools in Eclipse by doing this:

1. Launch Android SDK Manager
2. Select Tools->Options
3. Click "Enable Preview Tools"
4. Use the SDK Manager to uninstall the existing version of ADT
   and install preview tools

Confirmed that it is working on the MacBook Pro Retina 15".

Answer (score 0):

In the SDK Manager within Eclipse go to the menu bar, select Tools, Options. Enable Preview Channel and install version 21 of the the SDK. I'm using it right now on my Macbook Pro with Retina Display.

Answer (score 0):

As of Revision 22 of the SDK Manager "Enable Preview Tools" has been moved to Prefs:

1. Launch Android SDK Manager
2. Select Android SDK Manager->Preferences
3. Click "Enable Preview Tools"