# Eclipse + android SDK: error when launching apps for test

Tags: android, eclipse

Each time I make changes to XML file and press run button, It generates XML out file with 0 bytes and reports error.

So only way to test app is save the project, refresh it and only then it starts the app normally. Is's annoying. I have installed:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

on Mac OS X 10.7.3

and latest android SDK.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: right click your project and run it.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/2171031/1012284

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to run code when you are on a java file it is executing your xml file

Answer (score 0):

delete that .out file

and try to right click on project and run as android application