# Can not launch android project from xml layout file in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, launching-application

I've just updated `Eclipse IDE` for `android` to the newest version. In this version, when I press `ctrl + f11` in layout file (or any `xml file`,however in `activity` file, it works as expected), nothing happens!! It's not what I want! In the previous version of `Eclipse` (before updating), If I press `ctrl + f11` in xml file, my project will be launched! Does anyone has the same problem? Does anyone has suggestion to force my project launching from `xml` file when I press `ctrl + f11`?

Just one more thing, in `xml` layout file, I can use the `Graphical Layout`, but the `outline` of my `xml` file is missing from `code layout` (the beside part of `Graphical Layout`). Can anyone explain the reason? And how to solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2171123/1754112)

Comment: You can find a workaround [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2171123). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you run your project and if you opening your xml file, you can't run that project, instead what you can do is just click on any java activity and than press **Ctrl + F11**, that works.