# Hibernate / postgreSQL

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, installation

I am using Hibernate 3.6.4 on eclipse-Juno/EE with postgreSQL9.2.

I am not being able to run-- keep getting the following error log:

```
16:07:18,605 INFO  [main] Main  - javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=null
16:07:18,636 INFO  [main] Main  - java.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\endorsed
16:07:18,746 INFO  [main] Main  - launchFile: C:\Users\AYSE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.launching\launch\launch.xml

16:07:20,478 FATAL [main] Main  - No embedded stylesheet instruction for file: file:/C:/Users/AYSE/workspace/HiberAyse/src/hibernate.cfg.xml

org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.TransformationException: No embedded stylesheet instruction for file: 
file:/C:/Users/AYSE/workspace/HiberAyse/src/hibernate.cfg.xml

at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.transform(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:225)
at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.transform(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:186)
at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.Main.main(Main.java:73)

Caused by: org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.TransformationException: No embedded stylesheet instruction for file: 
file:/C:/Users/AYSE/workspace/HiberAyse/src/hibernate.cfg.xml
at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.transform(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:214)
... 2 more
```

From what I've looked up, this looks to be an error related to the creation of SessionFactory instance I am looking to use in the code.

My setup, configuration and the code should all be fine-- i followed a step-by-step video to put it all together.

Thanking for the help in advance.

Way too new to Hibernate.

In a separate Q, I'm about to ask on Hibernate-and-which-DB.

//=====================

EDIT: this is all mixed-- I'm getting an error msg but not this one. this is from running it on the cfg file-- as lifus noted in his comments &the ans below. i'll look to see more and come back w/whatever i've come up.

Comment: You are living the focus at hibernate.cfg.xml while running a program, right? If so, focus on a java class and run again.

Comment: if tried "versions" of that, right-clicked to run on the main-method-class, project folder and package folder.

Comment: That's pretty strange since eclipse is trying to "transform" your xml. [This might be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171031/how-to-stop-eclipse-from-trying-to-run-xml-files)

Comment: thx, will take a look. i since re-installed the DB and haggling for a bit on that setup

Answer (score 1):

> > Caused by: org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.TransformationException: No embedded stylesheet instruction for file: 
> >     file:/C:/Users/AYSE/workspace/HiberAyse/src/hibernate.cfg.xml

Eclipse is [trying to transform `hibernate.cfg.xml`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.xsl.doc%2Fhtml%2Flaunching%2Flaunching.html) [since it's default behavior for xml files](http://codingiscoding.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/eclipse-default-run-behavior-for-xml-files/) when xsl plugin is installed. This must be *Eclipse XSL Developer Tools*([`org.eclipse.wst.xsl.*` folders/jars in *plugin* folder](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3767)).

Make sure that focus is at *.java* file when you are trying to *run* your hibernate project.

Also, you may follow [these steps(and comments in case if this don't work for you either)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393103/android-sdk-main-out-xml-parsing-error/5469625#5469625) and [optionally these steps in case if you are not working with multiple projects at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171031/how-to-stop-eclipse-from-trying-to-run-xml-files/2171123#2171123).

Comment: The same error occured when the focus was on the `hibernate.cfg.xml` and not on the `.java file`.