# Why a "right click->Run as" on any project name in eclipse does not gives normal options sometime?

Tags: android, eclipse

Normally a "right click->Run as" on any project name in eclipse gives the options such as 
1 Run on Server
2 Android Application
3 Android Junit Test
4 Java Applet
etc. etc...
But Some time, it gives only two option
1 XSL transformation
2 Run configuration
Even of these two options, the first one is not clickable.
In this condition,I have to run the project from the run button(Run Sliding Menu) on the top midlle of Eclipse's screen, but from this I am not able to run a project of my choice(If there are many projects in the Package Explorer ),instead it runs the already selected project.

The same also happens for "Debug as" option.
Why it happens and how to set it to normal options?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2171031/645270)

Comment: It's not really random, but you're going to have to do a better job of figuring out how the projects are different.

Answer (score 0):

In that case: File->Restart, and everything should be fine